# Adding contents in two dimensional list

Tags: python-3.4

In Python, using IDLE 3.4 (x64), I have created a two-dimensional list of 3 rows and 2 columns. I then had the list populate with random numbers.

Now I want to display the sum values in the rows and then display the sum of the columns, and I'm at a loss for how to do that.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import random

def main():
      #Create nested loop
      rows = 3
      cols = 2

      values = [[0,0],
                [0,0],
                [0,0]]

      #Generate random integers in list
      for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                  values[r][c] = random.randint(1, 100)

      #Display results
      print(values)

main()
```

Comment: Your example conveniently has the shape of a matrix.  What if the second row had four columns while the other two rows only had two?  How can you generalize you solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got:

```
import random

def main():
    #Create nested loop
    rows = 3
    cols = 2

    values = [[0,0],
              [0,0],
              [0,0]]

    #Generate random integers in list
    for r in range(rows):
          for c in range(cols):
                values[r][c] = random.randint(1, 100)

    #Display results
    print(values)

    sum_2 = 0
    sum_3 = 0
    sum_2_list = []
    sum_3_list = []
    length = len(values)
    for num in range(0, length):
        sum = values[num][0] + values[num][1]
        print('{} + {} = {}'.format(values[num][0], values[num][1], sum))

    for num2 in range(0, length):
        sum_2 = sum_2 + values[num2][0]
        sum_3 = sum_3 + values[num2][1]

    print('{} + {} + {} = {}'.format(values[0][0], values[1][0], values[2][0], sum_2))
    print('{} + {} + {} = {}'.format(values[0][1], values[1][1], values[2][1], sum_3))
```